# Date Picker & Time Picker Conditions in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datetime, telerik

I have telerik Rad Datepicker & Time Picker.I wanted to check when someone select Startdate Before Enddate & Also start time before Endtime Here i use for that,

Start Date : 1/31/2013
End Date :   1/1/2013

Start Time : 10:00:00 AM
End Time :   11:00:00 AM

In the above example StartDate & EndDate is wrong but Starttime & EndTime is correct.Like this scenario my below code doen't show the error.

My Javascript Code is

```
 function validatenow(sender, args) {
    debugger;
    var StartDateControl = $find("<%= rdpStDt.ClientID %>");
    var SD = new Date(StartDateControl.get_selectedDate());
    var EndDateControl = $find("<%= rdpEd.ClientID %>");
    var ED = new Date(EndDateControl.get_selectedDate());
    var StartTimeControl = $find("<%= rtpSt.ClientID %>");
    var ST = new Date(StartTimeControl.get_selectedDate());
    var EndTimeControl = $find("<%= rtpEt.ClientID %>");
    var ET = new Date(EndTimeControl.get_selectedDate());
     args.IsValid = true;
    if((SD > ED ) || (ST > ET)){  //if startdate or time is larger than enddate or time it shows the error.
         args.IsValid = false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me why thisone is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use moment.js for date time manipulation. Please read the following for detail

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Comment: Can you add some sort of debugging code in there, and find out what values exactly these controls are returning. As i do not have telerik control difficult for me to find out what is going on.

Comment: One thing you can try, as per documentation get_selectedDate method returns date object so you do not need to create a date object yourself by calling new date (), remove that part and compare raw values returned by controls.

Comment: Also you can use compare validation control to achieve the same. Following the link to an article. http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/validation/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your Dates in javascript to integers and then compare them. See if that works.